# A question on minimizing $\| . \|_2^2$ vs $\| . \|_2$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Is the problem of $d(x,Y) = \inf\{ \| x - y\|^2 : y \in Y\}$

equivalent to $d(x,Y) = \inf\{ \| x - y\| : y \in Y\}$

Pardon me, let us keep it simple and just stick with the $\ell^2$ norm. I do not believe it is true under other $\ell^p$ oems

Comment: You always (for all norms) have $$\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert^2 : y \in Y\} = \left(\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\}\right)^2,$$ since the square is continuous, and monotonic on $[0,\infty)$. For the $\ell^2$-norm, the left hand side might be easier to compute.

Comment: So is it not true that $\inf\{ \| x - y\|^2 : y \in Y\} \iff \inf\{ \|x - y \| \}$? On $\mathbb{R}^2$, don't we have $\min \sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2} \iff \min (x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2$?

Comment: If the infimum is attained, it is attained for the same point(s) with or without the square, and if it is not attained, both have the same minimising sequences/nets. The _value_ of the infimum is only the same if it is $0$ or $1$ (or $\infty$, if $Y = \varnothing$).

Comment: Do you mean the square root and not the *square*?

Comment: No, I meant the square. But it's the same for the square root, it only depends on what you look at. I looked at $\lVert x-y\rVert$, and continuity and monotonicity say we can apply $t\mapsto t^2$ and $\inf$ in either order to that, getting the same result. If you start from $\lVert x-y\rVert^2$, you'd use the square root instead.

Comment: But in your second comment, you are actually meant (on the RHS) $\left(\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\}\right)^2$, and not $\left(\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\}\right)$. Or do you actually mean to say $t = \inf$ in this case? Hence the equivalence?

Comment: In the second comment, I meant $$\left(\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert^2 : y \in Y\} = \inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\}\right) \iff \left(\inf \{ \lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\} \in \{0,1,\infty\}\right).$$ Since, as I said in the first comment, the value of the one infimum is the square of the value of the other infimum.

Comment: The LHS of the equality is different from what you have in the first, so you do mean that $\inf \{ \} = (\inf \{ \})^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any norm $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$, and any continuous monotonically increasing function $f \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, define

$$\begin{align}
d(x) &:= \inf\left\lbrace\lVert x-y\rVert : y \in Y\right\rbrace,\\
D_f(x) &:=\inf \left\lbrace f\left(\lVert x-y\rVert\right) : y \in Y\right\rbrace.
\end{align}$$

Then you have the equality

$$D_f(x) = f\left(d(x)\right),$$
and if either infimum is attained, so is the other, and in the same points $y\in Y$. If neither infimum is attained, the same sequences/nets are minimising sequences/nets for both infima.

Minimising $\lVert x-y\rVert^2$ is equivalent to minimising $\lvert x-y\rVert$ if you are interested in the $y\in Y$ that attain or approximate the infimum, but not if you are interested in the value $d(x)$ resp. $D_f(x)$, although under the stated assumptions of continuity and monotonicity, the values are intimately related. You can always compute $D_f(x)$ from $d(x)$ then. If $f$ is strictly monotonic, so it has a continuous inverse, then computing $d(x)$ and $D_f(x)$ is equivalent in the sense that you can compute each value from the other.

Comment: Alright, thanks.